# How to get custom output on vstest console?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have some data driven tests written in Visual Studio 2012. When I run the tests from console by running following command in Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt **vstest.console.exe myTestSuite.dll**, I get following message:

> Starting test execution, please wait... 
>   Passed myTest (Data Row 0)
>   Passed myTest (Data Row 1)
>
> ...
>
> and so on...
>
> ...
>
> Total tests: 10. Passed: 10. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
>
> Test Run Successful.
>
> Test execution time: 53.4545 Seconds

How can modify this output from within my tests? I would like to print something like this:

> ---
>
> Starting MyFirstDataDrivenTest
>
> MyFirstDataDrivenTest Passed
>
> Execution Time: 2.1111 seconds
>
> ---
>
> Starting MySecondDataDrivenTest
>
> MySecondDataDrivenTest failed.
>   Login Exception occurred. Please check the input credentials.
>   Execution Time: 4.2222 seconds
>
> ---
>
> ...
>
> and so on...
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> Total tests: 10
>
> Passed: 9
>
> Failed: 1
>
> Skipped: 0
>
> Test Run Failed.
>
> Test execution time: 53.4545 Seconds

I have tried testContextInstance.WriteLine() , Console.WriteLine(), Debug.WriteLine(), Trace.WriteLine(). Nothing is working. testContextInstance.WriteLine() writes on the console only when a test fails.

I was able to achieve similar functionality in Visual Studio 2010 by following command:

**MSTest /testcontainer:"myTestSuite.dll" /detail:stdout**

But this is not supported in Visual Studio 2012.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.